# Generate choice field with existing ORM data in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using Django 1.4 with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I'm going to continue to update this question as I make progress.

UPDATE 2:

I'm trying to generate 2 choice fields in a form using information from an existing model.

```
class AssignProject(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, devs, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        ..  method:: __init__()

            Class constructor

            :param devs: Tuple with which developer
        """
        super(AssignProject, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.dev = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select(), choices = devs, required = True)
        self.designer = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select(), choices = devs, required = True)
```

At this point I can't seem to access `dev` and `designer` `ChoiceField` in my template yet.

Here is the view:

```
@login_required
def view_all_projects(request):
    """
    ..  function:: view_projects()

        Show the projects

        :param request: Django Request object
    """
    data = { 'user' : request.user }
    if (request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_superuser):
        all_projects = Projects.objects.filter(active = True)
        dev_info = User.objects.filter(is_staff = True, is_superuser = False)

        dev_dict = {}
        for dev in dev_info:
            dev_dict[dev.id] = '{0} {1}'.format(dev.first_name, dev.last_name)

        devs = tuple(dev_dict.items())

        form = AssignProject(devs)
        data.update({ 'form' : form })
        data.update({ 'projects'  : all_projects })
        data.update(csrf(request))
        return render_to_response("view_all_projects.html", data)

    return render_to_response("index.html", data)
```

I have verified that the developers/designers are properly getting set in the `devs` `tuple`.

...and the template from `view_all_projects.html`:

```
<form action="/assignProject/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="project_id" value={{ project.id }}>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><label class="formlabel">Assign Developer:<br /></label></td><td>{{ form.dev }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><label class="formlabel">Assign Designer:<br /></label></td><td>{{ form.designer }}</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><label class="formlabel">&nbsp;</label></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit  &#9658;"></td>
                </tr>
        </td>    
    </table>
</form>
```

I don't see any errors, but I do see a strange object reference in place of the `ChoiceField` in the template.

```
<django.forms.fields.ChoiceField object at 0x7ffdbc054190>
<django.forms.fields.ChoiceField object at 0x7ffdbc0542d0>
```

I see these instead.  I know I'm close...just can't quite get what I'm going wrong.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was entirely in the form `__init__`.

I should have assigned the fields like follows:

```
class AssignProject(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, devs, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        ..  method:: __init__()

            Class constructor

            :param devs: Tuple with developers
        """
        super(AssignProject, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['dev'] = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select(), choices = devs, required = True)
        self.fields['designer'] = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select(), choices = devs, required = True)
```

Note the `self.fields['dev']` not `self.dev`.  Fixed everything.